# Modify ceiling fan reverse switch to be on/off switch instead?

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

I have a typical ceiling fan in my room. It has a 3 speed chain, a lights on/off chain, and a switch to reverse direction of rotation. Is there a way to modify the wiring of the reverse switch such that it rotates anti-clockwise in one position, but simply shuts the fan off in the other position (instead of clockwise rotation)? Do I understand correctly that simply cutting one wire attached to the reverse switch should do this? If so, how to determine which one?

Comment: I assume you've tried disconnecting the wires one at a time to see which one does the job?

Comment: I understand that it's annoying to have to pull the chain multiple times to turn it on/off, especially if you're not sure which speed it's currently at, but, in my experience, the reverse switch is small and inconvenient and would certainly be more effort to reach and flip than pulling the chain. Are you sure this is the route you want to go? You may consider rephrasing the question "how can I have a single switch to turn on/off my ceiling fan if I cannot install a wall switch?" and list your method as the option you thought of. You may get some easier to implement & use ideas.

Comment: I presume, of course, that you cannot install a switch on the wall which would be, by far, the easiest & most convenient way to turn the fan on/off, in the long run.

Comment: @Chenmunka I am hesitant to experiment like that, but perhaps I can do it slowly, by disconnecting electricity, making a change, reassembling the fan, try it out and then repeat... Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Kagaratsch that's _exactly_ the way to do it safely! You shouldn't need to _completely_ reassemble the fan between tests, but be 100% certain that _any_ wire that isn't currently connected has a wire nut over the end of it to ensure that it cannot possibly short anything out. Be sure to flip the power off at the breaker - you'd want to do this even if there was a wall switch - it's too easy for someone to accidentally turn on a wall switch, much more difficult to accidentally turn on a breaker. ;)

Comment: Consider replacing the current 3-speed pull-chain switch with a simple on/off pull-chain switch instead.